# Are the Local Churches (associated with Watchman Nee) Calvinist?

Tags: reformed-theology, watchman-nee, local-churches

Are the [Local Churches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_churches_(affiliation)), based on the teachings of [Watchman Nee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchman_Nee) and [Witness Lee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witness_Lee), Calvinist (Reformed Theology)?

Comment: I don't know the "local Church" people. I assume they are theologians we might know about. If not, this is too localized. If they are, good question. "Compare the theologies of these people."

Comment: [Watchman Nee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchman_Nee) is quite a well known person. I hadn't heard of the [Local Churches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_churches_(affiliation)) but it seems they're a thing as well, but it is Local Church**es**, not Local Church.

Comment: @user47368 Would you like us to edit this to ask whether the Local Churches are Calvinist?

Comment: @curiousdannii : Sure, do whatever's necessary so the question actually gets a Biblical answer rather than arguments of why this is not a valid question :-)